# Updating AngularJS from 1.5.0 to 1.5.8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I have the following bower.json file:

```
{  
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "^1.5.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "bootstrap-rtl": "^3.4.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.6",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
    "angular-translate": "^2.11.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.5.7",
    "angular-messages": "^1.5.6",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.5.8",
    "angular-ui-grid": "^3.1.1",
    "angular-ui-sortable": "^0.14.2",
    "angular-bootstrap-affix": "^0.2.2",
    "theia-sticky-sidebar": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router-title": "^0.0.4",
    "angularjs-slider": "^4.0.2",
    "angular-fcsa-number": "^1.5.3",
    "angularPrint": "angular-print#^0.3.8",
    "ng-virtual-keyboard": "^0.3.0",
    "keyboard": "^1.26.1",
    "angular-spinner": "^0.8.1",
    "ng-ip-address": "^1.1.10",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.2",
    "ng-iban": "^1.1.0",
    "pdfmake": "^0.1.20",
    "ng-device-detector": "^3.0.1",
    "checklist-model": "^0.10.0",
    "angular-dynamic-number": "^2.1.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "^12.2.13",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "^12.2.13",
    "angular-ui-select": "^0.19.6",
    "angular-dragula": "^1.2.8",
    "angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-slick-carousel": "^3.1.7",
    "angular-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "drag-drop-webkit-mobile": "^1.2.0",
    "iban": "^0.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^5.0.9"
  }
}
```

I want to update only AngularJS to version `1.5.8`. What is the best way to do this update without any headache? I tried to install `bower install angular#1.5.8 --save` , but when other team members entered `bower-update` their whole project broke because a lot of packages where updated.
Any bright idea how to only update AngularJS?

Comment: It should not break while you  using `^` which just update minor package versions. Just run `bower update` and see what happends. "It should" - this is truly depending on the packages and its developers.

Comment: Try updating the `bower.json` file, delete angularjs from your `bower_components` and then run `bower install`. It should only install the missing dependency.

Comment: @Lin `angular-messages`, `angular-animation` and lots of other dependencies where updated to `1.6.x` version which caused project to break.

Comment: @fubar what about other angular libraries? like `angular-mocks`, `angular-animation` and ...? should I do the same about them? update them to corresponding angular version?

Comment: you should update them to the same version as your angular library

Comment: Angular mock versions does not corresponding to the angular version. Why `1.6.x` you said `1.5.0 to 1.5.8`?

Comment: @lin because I used `bower-update` command.

Comment: Yea, that doesnt match to your question. What you want? 1.5.0 to 1.5.8? or all to latest?

Comment: `NPM` has a `shrinkwrap` feature allowing you full control over your dependencies but also your nested dependencies (3rd party dependencies). There is a [github issue](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/505) to implement such a feature for `Bower`. However a quick Google brought up loads of libs that claim to achieve the same behavior for `Bower`. We implemented shrink-wrapping in `NPM` and these issues haven't arisen since. Just FYI really.

Comment: @lin I want to use this libarry https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng , it says that it requries angular 1.5.8 at least, what should I do with the given bower.json file ? :)

Comment: Try `"angular": "1.5.8",` and run `bower update` not `bower-update`. You may going to switch to tilde `~` on all your dependencies to ensure only the minor versions going to updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `"angular": "1.5.8"`, and run `bower update` not `bower-update`. You may going to switch to tilde `~` on all your dependencies to ensure only the minor versions going to be updated. Note that `angular-mocks` is not corresponding with the AngularJS version.

> In the simplest terms, the tilde matches the most recent minor version
>   (the middle number). ~1.2.3 will match all 1.2.x versions but will
>   miss 1.3.0.
>
> The caret, on the other hand, is more relaxed. It will update you to
>   the most recent major version (the first number). ^1.2.3 will match
>   any 1.x.x release including 1.3.0, but will hold off on 2.0.0.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.5.8",
        "angular-mocks": "~1.5.7",
        "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
        "bootstrap-rtl": "~3.4.0",
        "font-awesome": "~4.6.3",
        "moment": "~2.13.0",
        "angular-animate": "~1.5.6",
        "angular-sanitize": "~1.5.6",
        "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.15",
        "angular-translate": "~2.11.0",
        "angular-touch": "~1.5.7",
        "angular-messages": "~1.5.6",
        "angular-cookies": "~1.5.8",
        "angular-ui-grid": "~3.1.1",
        "angular-ui-sortable": "~0.14.2",
        "angular-bootstrap-affix": "~0.2.2",
        "theia-sticky-sidebar": "~1.4.0",
        "angular-ui-router-title": "~0.0.4",
        "angularjs-slider": "~4.0.2",
        "angular-fcsa-number": "~1.5.3",
        "angularPrint": "angular-print#~0.3.8",
        "ng-virtual-keyboard": "~0.3.0",
        "keyboard": "~1.26.1",
        "angular-spinner": "~0.8.1",
        "ng-ip-address": "~1.1.10",
        "file-saver": "~1.3.2",
        "ng-iban": "~1.1.0",
        "pdfmake": "~0.1.20",
        "ng-device-detector": "~3.0.1",
        "checklist-model": "~0.10.0",
        "angular-dynamic-number": "~2.1.1",
        "ng-file-upload": "~12.2.13",
        "ng-file-upload-shim": "~12.2.13",
        "angular-ui-select": "~0.19.6",
        "angular-dragula": "~1.2.8",
        "angular-drag-and-drop-lists": "~2.0.0",
        "angular-slick-carousel": "~3.1.7",
        "angular-slick": "~0.2.1",
        "drag-drop-webkit-mobile": "~1.2.0",
        "iban": "~0.0.8",
        "highcharts": "~5.0.9"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only updating your angular package will work locally, but when a new project needs to be setup and you want to install your dependencies you'll run into this problem any ways. I suggest you setup your dependencies how you want them and make sure you don't allow deviations to version you don't want to get installed. I'll add some info on how interpret the version numbers.

Using `bower update <package_name>` will update only that package to the version listed in the `bower.json`

Assume a version number like this: `1.5.0`.
Each number has a mean, `1` is the major version, `5` is the minor version and `0` is the patch number. So like this `major.minor.patch`

A caret (`^`) means you can't change major version, but you can change minor and patch version. So `^1.5.0` can range from `1.5.0` until but no including `2.0.0`. So in your cause because you had `^1.5.0`, Angular will update to the latest non-major version change which is `1.6.3`

A tilde (`~`) means only the patch version change (or minor version if patch isn't specified in the version)

Read more about it here: [semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#prerelease-identifiers)